# Questions of xgboost with R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, xgboost

I used `xgboost` to do logistic regression. I followed the steps [from](http://mirrors.opencas.cn/cran/), but I got two problems.The datasets are found [here](http://www.pkbigdata.com/common/competition/148.html#competeData).

First, when I run the follow code:

```
bst <- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix, label = output_vector,nrounds = 39,param)
```

Then, I got

```
 [0]train-rmse:0.350006
 [1]train-rmse:0.245008
 [2]train-rmse:0.171518
 [3]train-rmse:0.120065
 [4]train-rmse:0.084049
 [5]train-rmse:0.058835
 [6]train-rmse:0.041185
 [7]train-rmse:0.028830
 [8]train-rmse:0.020182
 [9]train-rmse:0.014128
[10]train-rmse:0.009890
[11]train-rmse:0.006923
[12]train-rmse:0.004846
[13]train-rmse:0.003392
[14]train-rmse:0.002375
[15]train-rmse:0.001662
[16]train-rmse:0.001164
[17]train-rmse:0.000815
[18]train-rmse:0.000570
[19]train-rmse:0.000399
[20]train-rmse:0.000279
[21]train-rmse:0.000196
[22]train-rmse:0.000137
[23]train-rmse:0.000096
[24]train-rmse:0.000067
[25]train-rmse:0.000047
[26]train-rmse:0.000033
[27]train-rmse:0.000023
[28]train-rmse:0.000016
[29]train-rmse:0.000011
[30]train-rmse:0.000008
[31]train-rmse:0.000006
[32]train-rmse:0.000004
[33]train-rmse:0.000003
[34]train-rmse:0.000002
[35]train-rmse:0.000001
[36]train-rmse:0.000001
[37]train-rmse:0.000001
[38]train-rmse:0.000000
```

`train-rmse` is finally equal to 0! Is that normal? Usually,I know `train-rmse` can't be equal to 0. So,where is my problem?

Second, when I run

```
importance <- xgb.importance(sparse_matrix@Dimnames[[2]], model = bst)
```

Then, I got a Error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Yes' not found.

I don't know what does it mean, maybe the first question leads to the second one.

```
library(data.table)
train_x<-fread("train_x.csv")
str(train_x)
train_y<-fread("train_y.csv")
str(train_y)
train<-merge(train_y,train_x,by="uid")
train$uid<-NULL
test<-fread("test_x.csv")
require(xgboost)
require(Matrix)
sparse_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(y~.-1, data = train)
head(sparse_matrix)
output_vector = train[,y] == "Marked"
param <- list(objective = "binary:logistic", booster = "gblinear",
          nthread = 2, alpha = 0.0001,max.depth = 4,eta=1,lambda = 1)
bst <- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix, label = output_vector,nrounds = 39,param)
importance <- xgb.importance(sparse_matrix@Dimnames[[2]], model = bst)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem (Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Yes' not found.) and the reason was the following:

I tried to do

```
dt = data.table(x = runif(10), y = 1:10, z = 1:10)
label = as.logical(dt$z)
train = dt[, z := NULL]
trainAsMatrix = as.matrix(train)
label = as.matrix(label)

bst <- xgboost(data = trainAsMatrix, label = label, max.depth = 8,
               eta = 0.3, nthread = 2, nround = 50, objective = "reg:linear")
bst$featureNames = names(train)
xgb.importance(model = bst)
```

The problem comes from the line

```
label = as.logical(dt$z)
```

I got this line in there because the last time I used xgboost, I wanted to predict a categorial variable. Now since I want to do regression it should read:

```
label = dt$z
```

Maybe something similar causes the problem in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is of any help. I'm often getting the same error when the labels have zero variation. Using the current CRAN version of xgboost, which is somewhat old already (0.4.4). xgb.train happily accepts this (showing a .50 AUC) but the error then shows when calling xgb.importance.

Cheers

Otto

```
[0] train-auc:0.500000  validate-auc:0.500000
[1] train-auc:0.500000  validate-auc:0.500000
[2] train-auc:0.500000  validate-auc:0.500000
[3] train-auc:0.500000  validate-auc:0.500000
[4] train-auc:0.500000  validate-auc:0.500000

[1] "XGB error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'Yes' not found\n"
```

Comment: I see the same error when my train-auc is 0.5000 and I therefore have no variance in predictions.